# Injecting factories into controllers with angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oop

I am working to get a deeper understanding of factories and constructors.  I am a bit confused however about where to put the instances and how to print them out.  I am getting back Plate is not defined.

Here is how I have configured my js file

```
var app = angular.module('dinerApp', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider){
  $routeProvider.when('/basque',{
    templateUrl:"./client/app.html",
    controller: 'AppCtrl'
  })
  .when('/menu',{
    templateUrl:"./client/menu.html",
    controller:'MenuCtrl'
  })
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/basque'
  });
});
```

Here is my factory I have placed the constructor  and its prototype in the factory.  I am working to make a basic restaurant menu.

```
app.factory('diner', function($q,$http){

  var Plate = function(name, description, price, ingredients){
    this.name = name;
    this.description =description;
    this.price = price;
    this.ingredients = ingredients; 
  };

  Plate.prototype.toString= function(){
    var returnString='' ;
    returnString += "name" + this.name + "\n" +
    "description: " + this.description + "\n" +
    "price: " + this.price + "\n";

    return returnString;
  };

  return Plate;
})
```

Below is my controller.  I have created a few instances.

```
app.controller('MenuCtrl',function($scope,diner){

var steakSandwich= new diner.Plate('Steak Sandwich', 'Something nice and tasty', 11.75);
var lambShoulderSteak = new Plate('Lamb Shoulder Steak','Something Different', 11.75);
var lambChops = new Plate('Lamb Chops', 'why not', 14.75);
var chickenSandwich = new Plate('chicken Breast Sandwich', 'basque chicken on a bun',9.75);
var basqueBurger = new Plate('Basco Burger', 'a better burger', 9.75);

$scope.plates = diner.Plate;
});
```

In my html I would ideally be calling ng-repeat

```
<ul ng-repeat="plate in plates"> 
  <li>{{plate.name}} </li>
  <li>{{plate.description}}</li>
  <li>{{plate.price}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dylan is right. You messed up with your namespaces of your factory. Get proper objects and put them to the scope like this.

[working plunkr of your factory](http://plnkr.co/edit/2rkXIX)

```
app.factory('Plate', function(){

  var Plate = function(name, description, price, ingredients){
    this.name = name;
    this.description =description;
    this.price = price;
    this.ingredients = ingredients; 
  };

  Plate.prototype.toString= function(){
    var returnString='' ;
    returnString += "name" + this.name + "\n" +
    "description: " + this.description + "\n" +
    "price: " + this.price + "\n";

    return returnString;
  };

  return Plate;
})

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, Plate) {
  var steakSandwich= new Plate('Steak Sandwich', 'Something nice and tasty', 11.75);
  var lambShoulderSteak = new Plate('Lamb Shoulder Steak','Something Different', 11.75);
  var lambChops = new Plate('Lamb Chops', 'why not', 14.75);
  var chickenSandwich = new Plate('chicken Breast Sandwich', 'basque chicken on a bun',9.75);
  var basqueBurger = new Plate('Basco Burger', 'a better burger', 9.75);
  var diner = [];
  diner.push(steakSandwich, lambShoulderSteak,lambChops,chickenSandwich,basqueBurger);

  $scope.plates = diner;

  angular.forEach(diner, function (plate) {
    console.debug(plate.toString());
  });

});
```

Checkout the console to check your toString().

Comment: Huge thanks to both of you.   The errors are pretty obvious when some one else sees and reviews it.  However, being new to Angular I found the whole process quite confusing.

Answer (score 0):

You're returning `Plate` from your factory, therefor `diner` is `Plate`, it does not have a property `Plate`. You should either call your `factory` "Plate" and new it up directly, or return an object with a `Plate` property.

Comment: Thanks man, I am new to Angular and definitely have a ways to go.